# confused over mips I-Type Instruction syntax

Tags: mips, mips32

Sorry about this really stupid question. But I have been reading my textbook the entire day and its getting really confusing.

I would like to clarify some syntax related questions with MIPS I-type instructions.

I understand that instructions like

```
addi $21, $22, -50
```

are possible and the immediate value is interpreted as a decimal (2s complement).

But can I write `addi $21, $22, 0xF1DF?` such that the immediate value is in hexadecimal?

That brings me to my next question with `andi $10, $11, 0xFFFF` and `ori $8, $0, 0x0FA5`. I understand that these 2 codes are correct.

But can I write `andi $10, $11, 120` and `ori $8, $0, -16`such that the immediate values are in decimal?  If it is possible, does it interpret `120` as hexadecimal or does it convert decimal `120` to hexadecimal which equates to `78` in hexadecimal.

I am very confused.

Comment: This is really a question about the assembler, not the processor. What assembler are you using?

Comment: @RaymondChen just normal QTSpim. I am also questioning if it is applicable in written exams

Comment: Then read [the documentation for that assembler](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/HP_AppA.pdf). Page A-47, "Assembler syntax." ("Just normal QTSpim" makes it sound like "Well certainly everybody uses QTSpim as their assembler, right?" I don't think that's true. For education, MARS is also popular. And for professional use, people are going to use something other than a simulator.)

Comment: I have read the documentation,  they do not explicitly say whether the immediate value is in decimal or hexadecimal form or could it be both?

Comment: Quoting page A-47: "Numbers are base 10 by default. If they are preceded by 0x, they are interpreted as hexadecimal. Hence, 256 and 0x100 denote the same value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express immediates in both base 10 or hexadecimal. To express an hedacimal value you need to use the `0x` prefix before the numeral (e.g. `0x10`, which is `16` in base 10). If you don't use the prefix `0x` before the numeral, the assembler will assume the numeral is in decimal notation.

Using your example, if you want to add `120` (base 10) you should encode the instruction like so `addi $10, $11, 120` or like so `addi $10, $11, 0x78`. The assembler will produce the same binary instruction `0x20000000`. You can try it for yourself [here](https://alanhogan.com/asu/assembler.php) with this online assembler.

Answer (score 0):

MIPS `addi` / `addiu` sign-extend the 16-bit immediate to 32 bits ([2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):
Values from `-32768` (0xFFFF8000) to `32767` (0x00007FFFF) are encodeable.

MIPS `andi` / `ori` *zero*-extend the 16-bit immediate to 32 bits,
Values from `0` (0x00000000) to `65535` (0x0000FFFFF) are encodeable.

**So no, you can't write `ori $8, $0, -16`, you'll have to use `addiu`.**
(Or inefficiently, `lui $8, 0xFFFF` / `ori $8, $8, 0xfff0`).

Usually you can leave this decision-making to the assembler, and let it choose how to create a constant with `li $8, 0xFFFFFFF0` or `li $8, -16`.  Those will assemble identically.

But if you're not just creating a constant, you do have to know what's encodeable.  For example, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/DKmWXO), gcc5.4 compiles these functions as follows for MIPS:

```
unsigned mask(unsigned a) {
    return a & -16UL;
}

      # not encodeable as an immediate for andi
    li      $2,-16                  # 0xfffffffffffffff0
    j       $31
    and     $2,$4,$2



unsigned mask_positive(unsigned a) {
    return a & 0xFF;
}

    j       $31
    andi    $2,$4,0x00ff   # encodeable as an immediate
```

---

The representation in the source is totally irrelevant; hex and decimal are 2 different serialization formats for numbers.  `0x10` and `16` are literally the same thing.  **In the MIPS machine code, they're stored in 16-bit binary, not hex or decimal**

`-32768` and `0xFFFF8000` are also the same thing (in 32-bit 2's complement).  It's also `0x8000` in 16-bit 2's complement.  And it's not representable as a 16-bit unsigned number, because `0x8000` zero-extends to `0x00008000` (+32768).